# What is the difference between file .git and directory .git?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I had a git submodule and I was in need to add some pre-commit operations, so i searched for the directory .git to find the hook and so on. Instead of the directory i found only a file

```
.git
```

So, i was guessing what does this means? (in order to start understanding what exactly i messed up fetching the submodule)

I tried searching but cannot find something useful to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.git/` folder contains the development history of you project and is located in your project's root directory.

The `.git` file is located in your submodule's root directory and contains the path to the `.git/` directory associated with this submodule (located in your project's `.git/modules/` directory)

Comment: so the hooks for the modules could be find in .git/modules/module_name of the principal project. Thank you! :D